# GnuPG show used ciphers

Tags: gnupg

Is it possible to display the ciphers used for encryption using GPG?

I figured out that using the verbose flags while decrypting yields the needed information:

> gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID 1122334455667788, created 2017-09-01
>
> gpg: AES256 encrypted data
>
> :compressed packet: algo=2

So I have two questions relating this.

- Is this information encrypted (using the public-key) ?
- Can the information be printed?

**Clarification:** I want to see the public-key algorithm and the symmetrical cipher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information is viewable with the `gpg` command:

```
mtak@rubiks:~/.password-store/test(master)$ gpg --list-packets -vv --show-session-key test.gpg
# off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=524
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid 0062798D743AC1D3
  data: [4096 bits]
gpg: public key is 0062798D743AC1D3
gpg: using subkey 0062798D743AC1D3 instead of primary key B3A64441695490BB
gpg: public key encrypted data: good DEK
# off=527 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=164 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
  length: 164
  mdc_method: 2
gpg: using subkey 0062798D743AC1D3 instead of primary key B3A64441695490BB
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID 0062798D743AC1D3, created 2016-07-27
      "Merijntje Tak <xxx@xxx.net>"
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: session key: '9:0712ABE10B7F0246B70A9138A3722E277028C6A1FA581A8CCEE6DC4B867E5AD6'
# off=548 ctb=ac tag=11 hlen=2 plen=121
:literal data packet:
  mode b (62), created 1514453162, name="zTDbDQ-test-test.txt",
  raw data: 98 bytes
gpg: decryption okay
```

The symmetric cipher is encrypted. When trying to '--list-packets' using a GPG that doesn't have access to the private key, it shows:

```
test@rubiks:~$ gpg --list-packets -vv --show-session-key test.gpg  
# off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=524
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid 0062798D743AC1D3
    data: [4095 bits]
gpg: public key is 0062798D743AC1D3
# off=527 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=165 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 165
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 0062798D743AC1D3
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Comment: I didn't think of using `file`. It's nice to display public-key cryptosystem but it __does not__ show the symmetrical algorithm.

Comment: You're right, I have updated my answer showing the asymmetric and symmetric algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The information in your example can be obtained using `gpg --list-packets`.

(Alternatively, `pgpdump` shows the same OpenPGP structures in a different format.)

Comment: Thanks! The list `gpg --list-packets`  doesn't show the AES part.  `gpg --list-packets --verbose` solved this. 

`pgpdump` reveals that the private key **is needed** to get the symmetric algorithm:  `Encrypted data [sym alg is specified in pub-key encrypted session key]`